# Https requests fail with axios

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I have found that there is server certificate sending with the https requests, i dont want to send any certificate. I am using axios please help. There is no problem with the http requests.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending HTTPS requests to a self-signed certificate? If so, you may need to implement something like the following...
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20488